# Alternative for Calendar function in Swift for ubuntu?

Tags: swift, docker, ubuntu, calendar, kitura

i am trying to build a running Docker Image for my Kitura AppServer.
I am doing the Coding in XCode on my MacBookbut i want to deploy the server to a Cloud Environment by using Docker.

This requires to make a build in Unix in my case an ibm Version of Ubuntu ...

FROM ibmcom/swift-ubuntu:5.0.2

Unfortunately the build process following the descriptions is quite frustrating and it takes some times multiple approaches to have a running image using the build commands listed here:
https://www.kitura.io/docs/deploying/docker.html

But every once in a while i have a working package. 
However after many trial and error i have learned that the Docker Image running on Ubuntu does not like my Calendar calls to get the day of the week.

```
var todayWeekday = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: timeZone!, from: date).weekday! - 1
```

This causes my container to stop with an exception and requires a restart...

Doe any one have an alternative solution to call reliable the day of the week with a function that can work with MacOS as well as Ubuntu ?

I dont want to write my own method as i fear i miss some factors that are coming with the complexity of dates.

Comment: Alternatively you could update to Swift 5.1 and use Calendar on Linux like you do on macOS.

Comment: Good hint .... thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there was a simple approach on that issue... 
I could use the DateFormatter()

```
let timeFormatWd = DateFormatter()
timeFormatWd.dateFormat = "e"

//New version of getting today Weekday !
let todayWeekday = Int(timeFormatWd.string(from: date))
```